# I am unable to add table caption to some of the tables in a quarto web page in R

Tags: r, quarto

I am trying to create a quarto web page. In this web page, I am unable to get table caption for some of the tables. In particular, this happens when the `{easystats}` package is involved.

````
```{r}
library(easystats)
library(broom)
```
````

Then I am creating a regression model using the mtcars dataset.

````
```{r}
lm_model <- lm(mpg~cyl+drat, data = mtcars)
```
````

Now I am trying to create table of regression information.

````
```{r}
#| tbl-cap: "Easystats"
#| label: tbl-easystats
model_parameters(lm_model)
```
````

Another way to extract same info using `{broom}` package.

````
```{r}
#| tbl-cap: "Broom"
#| label: tbl-broom
tidy(lm_model)
```
````

Out of these two, the "Broom" table gets the caption when I render the document, but the "Easystats" package doesn't get the caption. In the place of the caption, it shows `?Caption`. Is it something to do with the easystats package or is there some other issue?

Created on 2023-01-08 with reprex v2.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`?model_parameters`](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/model_parameters.html#note),

> The print() method (i.e. [`print.parameters_model`](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/print.parameters_model.html)) has several arguments to tweak the output.

> and a dedicated method for use inside rmarkdown files, [`print_md()`](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/display.parameters_model.html).

Also there is a `print_html()` function too. So you can pass the output of `model_parameters(lm_model)` to either `print_md()` or `print_html()`.

````
---
title: "Table Cap"
format: html
---

## Easystats in Quarto

```{r}
#| message: false
library(easystats)
lm_model <- lm(mpg~cyl+drat, data = mtcars)
```

```{r}
#| tbl-cap: "Easystats 01"
#| label: tbl-easystats01
model_parameters(lm_model) |> print_md()
```

```{r}
#| tbl-cap: "Easystats 02"
#| label: tbl-easystats02
model_parameters(lm_model) |> print_html()
```
````

---

[image: EasyStats in Quarto]

---